# Checking whether passed in date parameter to a stored procedure is older than a year

Tags: sql, sql-server, transactional

I have a stored procedure that has a variable that currently limits historical queries to the previous year.

The ask from the user is that we allow for searching back 2 years HOWEVER if the date range passed to the procedure in question is within the last year we still limit the searched data set to the past year for performance reasons.

We are currently limiting the query to the past year with this variable

```
 SET @yearago = CONVERT(numeric(8,0), CONVERT(char(8),       
 DATEADD(yy,-1,GETDATE()),112))
```

I know I can set the `DATEADD` parameter to -2 to increase the dataset but I need to find an elegant, lightweight way to determine when i should do that based on  the fromDate.  Transactional sql is not my forte and I can't find a good example of date comparisons in it.  I imagine this is an easy ask for some sql lovers out there..

Comment: Can you share the query you are currently using? Or at least the where predicates?

Answer (score 0):

```
DATEDIFF(d, @RequestedDate, GETDATE())
```

If it's greater than 365, it'd more than a year old. Hope that helps!

Answer (score 0):

Something like an "if/then statement" should work... here is an example I used based on the day the report runs. You can change the DateName function to DW (Day of the Week) or things like month, year or whatever in comparison to the date you are trying to pull in as a parameter...

```
Declare @DateTo as Date
Declare @DateFrom as Date

DECLARE @dayName VARCHAR(9);
SET @dayName = DATEName(DW, GETDATE());



IF(@dayName = 'Monday')
Begin 
    Set @DateTo = GETDATE()
    Set @DateFrom = DateAdd(dd,-3,GETDATE())
End
Else  
IF(@dayName <> 'Monday') 
Begin
    Set @DateTo = GETDATE()
    Set @DateFrom = DateAdd(dd,-1,GETDATE())
End
```